# array limitting to 10 values when there is no LIMIT set

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, limit

i have a code where it is to create an array key of the date which will group together and array value that will count the number of different id.. this is will be done when a user selects a "TO" and "FROM" date.. so as i was doing some testing i noticed something weird that the array only limits until 10 value. for example if i select date between 1/3/2018 - 20/3/2018 then it only returns from 1/3/2018 - 10/3/2018. why is this happening when i did not set any limit to it.
my code in controller:

```html
public function graphheheByDate(Request $request, $companyID)
{
  $companyID = $this->decode($companyID);

  $matchs = DiraChatLog::whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->orderBy('date_access', 'asc')->get();
  foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
    $time = strtotime($match->date_access); 
    $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
    $a[$newformat] = $this->testing($newformat,$match);
  }

  dd($a);

  $user = array_values($a);
  $dates = array_keys($a);
  // dd($user, $dates);

  $from = $request->from;
  $to = $request->to;
  // dd($from, $to);

  $companyID = $this->encodeID($companyID);

  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graphhehe', compact('companyID','from','to', 'dates'))->with('user',json_encode($user,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('dates',json_encode($dates,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));     
}
```

```html
private function testing($date,$match)
{
  $a = Carbon::parse($date)->addDay()->toDateTimeString();
  // dd($a,$date);

  $noOfUsers = DiraChatLog::whereBetween('date_access', [$date,$a])->get();
  // dd($noOfUsers);

  return $noOfUsers->groupBy('user_id')->count();
}
```

using this i have selected the dates 1/3/2018 - 20/3/2018 but its returning like
[image]

Comment: If you select a range of `4/3/2018 - 16/3/2018`, do you still get ten dates? In what range?

Comment: is that all of your testing code? Do you have a factory that creates 10 DiraChatLog?

Comment: @GreatBigBore then it returns the date 4/3 - 13/3

Comment: @user2749200 that is all my code for that function

Comment: what is the datatype of column `date_access`? and what is the value of `$request->from` and `$request->to`?

Comment: @Ben it is DATETIME. the value of both request is date

Comment: use `dd` or `var_dump` the `$request->from`

Comment: i selected 1/3/2018 so when i dd i get `2018-03-01`